# Use Optaplanner to determine which parcel deliveries we ship ourselves and which we outsource

Tags: algorithm, optaplanner

I work for a large online retailer in UK. We ship approaching 2000 orders each day and are growing very quickly.

We currently use multiple delivery firms to handle all our deliveries. We're planning to launch our own fleet of delivery vans soon for deliveries local to our distribution centre.

We're looking for a solution to determine which parcels we ship ourselves and which we outsource to our delivery partners and also solve the Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) or Capacitated VRP (CVRP). We were planning on using Optaplanner with real road times (based on OSRM) for the CVRP. I think we could use Optaplanner to also work out the issue of which deliveries we do ourselves and which we outsource, but I really don't know where to start.

**Can someone please point me in the right direction for using Optaplanner for determining which deliveries are made by our own vans and which are made using 3rd party delivery firms?**

You can assume that we know the following for all parcels:

1. Lat/long for each delivery point.
2. The actual driving time and distance between any two delivery points (and/or our distribution centre).
3. The cost of using a 3rd party to make each delivery.

We can probably know other things too if needed.

I have also asked a [related question on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/288983/work-out-which-parcel-deliveries-we-ship-ourselves-and-which-we-outsource), but that is regarding the concept as a whole, whereas this question is specifically on using Optaplanner to solve this problem. I'd really appreciate any help you can offer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with different vehicle types and hard/soft scoring rules, measuring the cost in money.

Rules for own fleet (regular CVRP):

- hard constraint: load cannot exceed vehicle capacity
- hard constraint: vehicle must return in time
- soft score in money: daily/hourly cost for vehicle and driver
- soft score in money: cost of fuel for distance traveled

Rules for outsourced delivery:

- hard constraint: limit number of packages delivered via 3rd party?
- soft score in money: cost per package

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to make OptaPlanner decide on whether or not to outsource a route the answer is scoring rules.

You would need to have a standard rule that encourages the engine to minimize driving time and a second rule that encourages it to minimize cost. The second rule would apply a different cost calculation based on whether or not the van is outsourced.

You will then need to add a weight factor to the scoring rule to tell the engine how important it is to lower the cost compared to minimizing the drive time. You can make this value customizable and teak it until you find one that generates the results that you want.

I believe the [cheap time schedulin](http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.2.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#cheapTimeScheduling)g example has some cost calculations in it.